# why isn't my AJAX load() working in this code?

Tags: html, ajax, dom

I have a script that loads an ul from an html page to a div on another page. It is meant to be my navigation menu, but it won't load. The ul has an id name and I'm using the id to load the ul and not loading the whole html page the ul is on.

```
//This is the page I want the ul to load to.

    <body>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

  //facebook registration init code omitted

</script>



//this is the div where I want the ul to load

<div id="nav">

</div>

// in this div is the facebook registration plug in iframe that shows after the fbinit code runs.

<div>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
             client_id=3967*****188&&
             redirect_uri=http://myDomain.com/signedRequest.php&
             fields=name,password"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="330">
 </iframe>

    </div> 


         <button>Button label</button>

// jqueru UI method
<script>
$(function(){
 $( "button" ).button(); 

});
</script>

//The rest of the page markup omitted

</body>
</html>   

//this is the script where I call the load()
//The load to #mainDiv is for use on another page
//note that I'm only trying to load the ul with id navig, and not the whole html page. 

$(function(){

$("#mainDiv").load("http://myDomain.com/find2.html");

$('#nav').load("http://myDomain.com/menu.html #navig");

});   

//this is the menu.html page with the ul. 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="navig">
    <li><a href="#"> gatherings I'm hosting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> gatherings I'm invited to</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `load()` function doesn't appear to be inside `<script></script>` tags.. have you tried putting it inside them? Are you receiving any errors in your console?

Comment: The function is on its own .js page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix this, it seems that the format of the address is wrong:
`$('#nav').load("http://myDomain.com/menu.html #navig");`

`#navig` is just a hash and not work in `SERVER-SIDE`, for applications it is `client-side`.

Good luck